# Change fmt:formatDate pattern dynamically

Tags: java, spring, localization, jstl, el

I need to change fmt:formatDate pattern dynamically depending on the localization.
I have the property file for each locale with the date.format key, somewhere it's value is MM/dd/YYYY, somewhere DD/MM/YYYY and so on.
In the JSP I have the following tag:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${dateToFormat}" pattern="<spring:message code='date.format' />" var="formattedDate" />
```

The Exception I get is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'p'`
What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the pattern is not coming in as you expected. Check to see what the spring message for date.format is.

Comment: It's simply the "MM/dd/YYYY" string