# Take fmt:formatDate's pattern from Properties File

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

fmt:formatDate pattern does not allow anything but a string

This is the LOC i am referring to

```
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="today" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate var="todayString" value="${today}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

I would like to pick the pattern from the properties file. Normally when I do spring:message inside same jsp file (I am using spring boot/jsp) I can see the message. So they are configured properly.
Is there a possible way for me to format my date as well as fetch the pattern from the properties file. I have tried many ways but mostly JSP throws exception.

[Change fmt:formatDate pattern dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783272/change-fmtformatdate-pattern-dynamically) does not answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

```
<fmt:message key="pattern.date" var="datePattern"/>
<fmt:formatDate var="todayString" value="${today}" pattern="${datePattern}"/>
```

Or:

```
<fmt:formatDate var="todayString"
                value="${today}"
                pattern="<fmt:message key='pattern.date'/>"/>
```

Comment: My i8nl was not configured properly.